# Dynamically setting media type @Produces annotation value

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jax-rs

I need to know if there is a way by which I can set the @Produces value from query parameter.
For example: if the query parameter value is 'JSON' then I want to set the method header as @Produces(application/json) or if it is 'XML' then I want to set it as @Produces(application/xml)

I know that we can specify multiple media types as 
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"}), but it is not working for me as it is giving me an error when the output is JSON.

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible repeat of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner

Comment: What is the error you're getting when producing JSON? Anyways, do not use `@Produces`, change the return type to `Response` as advised by @SotiriosDelimanolis in (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21053612/290799) and set the desired media type using `#type(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification has rules for what can go into an annotation's attributes. Specifically, [it says this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1)

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is not one of the following: **a primitive type,
>   String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type
>   (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type
>   is one of the preceding types.**

Basically, annotations (and their attributes' values) are meant to be compile time constants. So, no, you cannot change the value of the annotation itself.

What you can do is [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556897/changing-content-type-in-jax-rs-rest-service) and make your handler method return a `Response` object with the appropriate media type.