# How to change content-type header of http response provided by method in class annotated @RepositoryRestController

Tags: spring-boot, content-type, spring-data-rest, spring-restcontroller

I have class:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(value = "users")
public class UserController  {

...other methods...

@GetMapping(value = "returnText", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String returnText() {
        return "my text";
    }
}
```

And when this method is called by Postman, http response **content-type** header is **application/hal+json** but I used `produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE`.

Can I somehow change `content-type` header of response?

Can `@RepositoryRestController` only return `application/hal+json`?

I wanted to use `@RepositoryRestController` to return `image/jpg` contet-type also in another method and that does not work because of same reason.

I think this will work in `@RestController` class but why use that if my application is Spring Data Rest and I want to use `@RepositoryRestController` annotation for my controllers.

Comment: Please have a look at this maybe this can help.
visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556897/changing-content-type-in-jax-rs-rest-service

Comment: That are jax-rs not Spring annotations. So I don't think that will help me, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [SDR documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers):

> ...to take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, **message converters**, exception handling, and more, use the @RepositoryRestController annotation ...
>
> If you’re NOT interested in entity-specific operations but still want to build custom operations underneath **basePath**, such as Spring MVC views, resources, etc. use **@BasePathAwareController**.

So try to use `@BasePathAwareController` instead of `@RepositoryRestController`.